# Find the values of $p$ such that $n^p-n$ is divisible by $p$.

Tags: induction, proof-explanation

Find the values of $p$ such that $n^p-n$ is divisible by $p$.

I am aware that the answer is prime numbers and that this is called Fermat’s Little Theorem, but I am not sure why. By doing an induction argument:

Let $p(n)$ be the proposition that $n^p-n$ is divisible by p. The base case is trivial.

Assume $p(k)$ is true, $k^p-k=pA$ for some integer $A$.

$(k+1)^p-(k+1)=k^p+pk^{p-1}+pC2k^{p-2}+...+pk+1-k-1$

$=k^p-k+pk^{p-1}+pC2k^{p-2}+...pk$

which is divisible by $p$ from the assumption and the fact that $pCi$ is divisible by $p$ for all i $1\le i <p$

I don’t see where we use the fact that p is prime. Doesn’t this prove it for all integers?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number

Comment: 6 do not divide $\binom{6}{2}=15$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the inductive step> observe that

$$(n+1)^p=\sum_{k=0}^p\binom pk n^k=1+n^p+\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}\binom pk n^k$$

But every term in the last sum is sivisible by $\;p\;$ (check this: this is the gist and this is *not always* true for non-primes!), so

$$(n+1)^p-(n+1)=n^p+1+\text{someting divisible by}\;p-n-1+\ldots$$
Finish now the argument.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need any induction if you take for granted the basic version of *lil' Fermat*:

> If $p$ is prime and does  not divide $n$, then $\;n^{p-1}\equiv 1\mod p$

As a consequence, $\;n^p=n^{p-1}\cdot n\equiv 1\cdot n=n\mod p$ when $\; n\not\equiv 0\mod p$.

As to the case $n\equiv 0$, it is obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Not only primes but also Carmichael numbers. The necessary and sufficient condition that a number "n" is Carmichael number is that it should be a squarefree composite number and if p is a prime dividing n, then p-1 must divide n-1.